# JQuery UI Dialog + JQuery Validate + Tabbing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

I have a jquery ui dialog with a form inside. If I call the validate method of the jquery.validate plugin, tabbing inside the form fields strangely submits the form.

If I remove the call to validate, the odd behaviour dissapears, but then I would have to validate by hand.

Any ideas why?

Can't post code right now, but could create a simplification and post it if needed.

Comment: I would check for something that calls the submission in the validate function.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you mean by tabbing, but I had the same issue with dialog and form validation. First, it was picky about `<input type="submit" id="submit-your-enquiry" value="Send"/>` Then the submit itself, at the end I had to do the validation by myself and to be honest sounded logical for my usage.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit-your-enquiry').click(function(){
        if(validate_enquiry_form('#enquiry-form')){
            //$('#enquiry-form #submit-your-enquiry').hide();
            send_enquiry_form('#enquiry-form');
        }
        return false; //VERY IMPORTANT
    });
});
```

And my `send_enquiry_form was` just a simple `ajax`.

Hope it helps.